# Store whole format of a cell in a variable

Tags: excel, vba

**Background**

I want to write a simple function which swaps the contents of two selected (not necessarily adjacent) cells. I **do not** want to copy the cell to a temporary cell first. Thus, I really want to swap the cells in place.

**Challenge**

While simply *swaping* the content is rather easy by using a `Variant` temporary variable holding the content of cell 1, overwriting the content of cell 1 with the content of cell 2 and then writing back the content of the variant variable to cell 2, I struggle how to also copy all format related stuff. There are plenty of slots which need consideration (`.NumberFormat, .Interior` to name just two). Do I really need to copy each of them seperately or is there an easier way to swap the format *without* using any temporary cell?

**Code**

```
Public Sub SwapCells(Optional bolWithFormat As Boolean = True)
    'Purpose: switch the content of two cells
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim rngSel As Range
    Dim varContent As Variant
    Set rngSel = Selection
    If (rngSel.Count = 2) Then
        With rngSel.Cells(1)
            varContent = .Value
            .Value = rngSel.Cells(2).Value
            rngSel.Cells(2).Value = varContent
        End With
    Else
        'Do nothing, because swap makes only sense for exactly 2 cells
    End If
ErrHandler:
    Set rngSel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, you would need an object with all of the same properties ... and that's a cell. It would be nice to be able to specify a memory resident Sheet, Range, or Cell.

Comment: Afaik there's no `CellFormat`-Object or the like. What is your concern against using a temporary cell anywhere in your Workbook?

Comment: @Verzweifler I want to use this macro in my `Personal.xlsb`. Thus, it should work in any workbook and hence, I cannot make any assumptions about the structure. So whatever cell I choose there may be this one day where exactly this one cell is used. I know, very unlikely that I cannot find one single unused cell in `16384 * 1048576 = 17179869184` cells, but I tend to consider the most extreme use cases in whatever coding I do :-/

Comment: However, if the pain of copying all formats in VBA outweighs the pain of making an assumption about an empty cell, I may be intrigued to go for the temporary cell solution.

Comment: Why not use a cell in your personal workbook?

Comment: Or (assuming you don't have to deal with protected workbooks) you add a new worksheet, use it's cells and delete it afterwards?

Comment: @Rory Like the idea of the cell in the personal workbook, was not thinking about that. Can you post an answer, such that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments, using a temporary holding cell is much the easiest solution. You can use a cell in your Personal macro workbook to avoid worrying about finding a spare cell in the active workbook. It would probably be wise to set the `Saved` property of the personal workbook to True afterwards to avoid getting prompted to save that every time you quit Excel after running the macro!

Comment: Very good. Needed to do some more research to find out about the `Saved` property as I did not read the answer before - would have saved me even more time - perfect and fast answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, here's the final code (stored in my `Personal.xlsb`) which I use:

```
Public Sub SwapCellsGeneral(Optional bolWithFormat As Boolean = False)
    'Purpose: switch the content of two cells
    'Use Personal.xlsb to use a temporary cell and copy paste
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim rngSel As Range, rngTemp As Range
    Dim varContent As Variant
    Set rngSel = Selection
    Set rngTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    If (rngSel.Count = 2) Then
        If (bolWithFormat) Then
            rngSel.Cells(1).Copy rngTemp
            rngSel.Cells(2).Copy rngSel.Cells(1)
            rngTemp.Copy rngSel.Cells(2)
        Else
            With rngSel.Cells(1)
                varContent = .Value
                .Value = rngSel.Cells(2).Value
                rngSel.Cells(2).Value = varContent
            End With
        End If
    Else
        'Do nothing, because swap make only sense for exactly 2 cells
    End If
ErrHandler:
    'Set this to avoid asking if we want to save personal.xlsb
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Set rngSel = Nothing
    Set rngTemp = Nothing
End Sub
```